# Remove node from XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a xml config file that I am trying to remove a node from. My xml document is as follows

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="value1" value="27348614" />
  <add key="value2" value="123432" />
  <add key="removeMe" value="removeMeAsWell" />
</appSettings>
```

I have tried the following method

```
public void removeNode(XDocument AppStoreXML, string FOPath)
{
    var newElement = new XElement("add",
             new XAttribute("key","removeMe" ),
            new XAttribute("value", "removeMeAsWell"));
    AppStoreXML.Root.Descendants("appSettings")
            .First(s => s.Attribute("key").Value == "removeMe")
            .Remove(); //this returns the error Sequence contains no matching element
    //newElement.Remove(); this try returns no matching parent

    AppStoreXML.Save(FOPath);
}
```

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
AppStoreXML.Root.Descendants("appSettings")
```

You're trying to find descendant elements *of* `appSettings` which are also *called* `appSettings` and have the specified attributes. You want the `add` elements instead:

```
AppStoreXML.Root.Descendants("add")
```

Also, you might want to change `First()` to `Where` - that way you can find *multiple* elements to remove if you want to.